# iPhone 7 device logs won't show up in the debugger in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When building and running my app from Xcode on our iPhone 7's, I can't get the logs to show up in the debugging area. I've tested both mine and my wife's iPhone 7's. It's completely blank. They show up for other devices (iPhone 5, iPad, etc.) and for the simulators but not for the 7's.
When I view logs in **Window > Devices > (select device)**, or in the system's Console, I also don't see logs for my app. There's only references to the app from symptomsd, etc. But no process even appears with my apps name.
It seems there is some incompatibility between my app and these specific devices. I've been using and updating the same app since around 2012 so maybe there is some sort of cruft in there that is blocking logs on these very latest devices.
Things I've tried:

- Building and running other apps (logs show up)
- Testing other devices (logs show)
- Re-powering iPhone and restarting Xcode
- Setting a breakpoint and running a command in the debugger (I got response from that command)

Any other steps to try would be appreciated.

Comment: what are you using to log? Are you using swift or objective c?

Comment: @Axel I'm using `NSLog` if that's what you mean. Objective-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use also`dump` to log. You may try this, maybe this one works. What may help you:
 1. Create new building scheme.
 2. Try running it on simulator. Use many iOS versions. Maybe the latest one have a bug.
 3. Remove Derived data in this project.

Comment: Creating a new scheme did the trick! I'd forgotten that I'd disabled `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` (in Run > Arguments > Environment Variables), probably to quiet all the extra logging int he beta version of iOS. Thanks.